# What is the URL to use for inviting the users through email links to sign-up in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C account and I want to invite few people to sign-up though invitations only. Currently the sign-up site is [here](https://login.microsoftonline.com/familytreeplus.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Sign_In_Sign_Up/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?local=signup&csrf_token=STBwYml2UCtIaGprZ3JRUmVEbGI4SDZEeW1pTlhGYkhRMzAxS2tMK3NvcnN6YnRiZ3R2c0F0aGlYZTZTTms5NXpJbyszUHRWQ3lDbkU0UzdzK2RPUHc9PTsyMDE5LTA1LTMxVDEyOjExOjI2LjM0NTM4M1o7bGxoQXZ0SUdVRkcrMVBmdUlCV1Z6Zz09O3siT3JjaGVzdHJhdGlvblN0ZXAiOjF9&tx=StateProperties=eyJUSUQiOiI2YTY2OGQ4My04NGU2LTRhMWYtOWMxZS1jN2I1MmY1MmI2YmQifQ&p=B2C_1_Sign_In_Sign_Up).

- What URL should I send to the user to sign-up?
- Is there a way hide the field like `Country` in the sign-up form but takes the value from the invitation URL?

Comment: Have a look at this sample: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you are trying to get the sign-up URL for your user. Alright let's get started :)

1. What URL should I send to the user to sign-up?

You can get your sign-up `URL` from `azure portal`. Follow the below steps to get your sign-up `URL`

**Step:1**

Go to your `azure B2C Tenant` and click on `User flows (policies)` like below screen shot.

[image]

**Step:2**
You can create your new sign-up policy or click on your exiting sign-up policy. See the screen shot below.

[image]

**Step:3**

Run your sign-up policy by clicking on `Run user flow` button which shown on below picture.

[image]

**Step:4**

Once you click on `Run user flow` you would get following window. Just copy `Run user flow endpoint` this `URL` you have to send to your user for sign-up

[image]

**Step:5**

As you seen when user click on this `URL` they would shown below `sign-up` page.
[image]

2. Is there a way hide the field like Country in the sign-up form but
   takes the value from the invitation URL?

Yes you can do it in a very simple way. Just while creating your sign-up flow you would seen `4. User attributes and claims` see below screen shot:

[image]

click on `show more` you will be show a new window as you seen there are two row `Collect attribute` and `Return claim` check what you want to collect and need not to check what you want to hide. As I have check `Country` because I want to collect this information from from user and want hide in claims.

But for `Display Name` both I want to collect and return in claims. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Hope you understand. If you still have any problem feel free to share. Thanks and happy coding!